# Java 9: jigsaw and hibernate 5.2.12 doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, jta, java-9, java-platform-module-system

In my **pom.xml** file I have only one dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and also a **module-info.java**

```
module testmodule {
    requires hibernate.jpa;
    requires hibernate.core;
}
```

but when I'm trying to run my app I get the error: **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jboss.transaction.api.1.2.spec: Invalid module name: '1' is not a Java identifier**. Any thoughts how to deal with it?

Comment: What's the dependency for `requires hibernate.jpa;`? the question details seems incomplete, do you have `jboss.transaction.api.1.2.spec` in dependencies and module-info as well?

Comment: @nullpointer jboss.transaction.api.1.2.spec is a transitive dependency from hibernate-core...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the stacktrace, the exception is not for the hibernate-core module but for the 
`jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec` dependency included in your project.

Until the version `1.0.1.Final` of the dependency, the automatic module name could not be derived from the jar file name.

[image]

This has been though updated in their 2.0.0.Alpha1 release from October 2017 which now has a `module-info.class` packaged in the jar to get the module name from.

So, you can preferably use `2.0.0.Alpha1` version with module name `java.transaction` as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Alpha1</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works, I hope hibernate will work just fine with jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec version 2.0.0.Alpha1

Comment: I got such [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47964264/5314581) now, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

With the environment below works this way:

```
module testmodule {
    requires java.persistence;
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
}
```

Environment:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
```

hibernate version: `5.3.7.Final` -> depends on javax.persistence-api-`2.2`
com.fasterxml.jackson.core artefacts version: `2.9.7`
jackson-datatype-hibernate5 version: `2.9.7`
springframework version: `5.1.2.RELEASE`